# Divorcing Your Wife in MCA

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

In the Minecraft Mod "Minecraft comes Alive" you can marry villagers and have kids. The problems is I made a serious mistake in marrying someone who's traits are often "Rude/Obnoxious".

Is there any way to divorce her or do I have to commit an old fashioned murder?

Comment: What about staging an 'accident'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to a priest and click on it, then click the top-right button and then click divorce. If you don't have a priest, the only way to divorce her is to kill her.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to a priest or priestess and click the SPECIAL button.

There is a divorce spouse button, click that.
Once you do, your prior spouse is going to be mad at you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to a priest. Try using the spawn eggs until you get one.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Priests no longer exist in MCA. A Priestess or Father can only bless children.

Comment: OH!! I never knew that.